# Laravel Forge - Update Server Public SSH key

Tags: laravel, forge

So, for some reason I deleted my servers forge accounts SSH keys and created new ones. Now Laravel forge still has the old public key and it's the same it added to github. Is there a way to update the public ssh key that forge uses for my server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stole a script on how laravel forge itself is setup

```
# generate new ssh key
ssh-keygen -f /home/forge/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N ''

# Copy Source Control Public Keys Into Known Hosts File

ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /home/forge/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -H bitbucket.org >> /home/forge/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com >> /home/forge/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted only keys, not the whole user, you just needs to add public key again to the authorized_keys file.

```
sudo su forge
nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: I already recreated the server.. - what I was looking for is a way to update the public key that forge website adds to Github for automatic deployments

Comment: hi @EvansM. did you figure it out, could you answer your own question for all travelers from the future? :)